# .Htaccess - File extension gets not removed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, extension

I'm using the .htaccess below to remove the .html file extension but if someone types in

> example.com/test

into the browser it redirects to

> http://www.example.com/test.html

.

Why does the .html gets added and not removed?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The line doing the substitution is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
```

which will unconditionally add `.html` to any request where the only slash after the hostname is the last character (e.g. `http://example.com/test/`, but not `http://example.com/test1/test2/`).

If you want to strip `.html`, try this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1
```

Comment: Try it and it does not remove the .html. It's the same as before. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1` What else could I try?